# Pysnmp can't get multiple oids if one of them is not found using SNMPv1

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

When I use pysnmp and try to get multiple oids in one getCmd command, but one of the oids does not exist then I can't receive any of the oids' values, unless i use SNMPv2 or SNMPv3(change mpmodel in the code)

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, error

def cbFun_OID(sendRequestHandle, errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds, cbCtx):
    (authData, transportTarget) = cbCtx
    for oid, val in varBinds:
        print val.prettyPrint()
ip='192.168.0.101'
cmdGen = cmdgen.AsynCommandGenerator()
cmdGen.getCmd(
   cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
   cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
   ((1,3,6,1,2,1,43,10,2,1,4,1,1),(1,3,6,1,2,1,43,5,1,1,1,1,123456)),
   (cbFun_OID, (cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0), cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)))))
cmdGen.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
```

If both of the oids exist i get two values.
If at least one of the oids doesn't exist then all the values will be 'No Such Object currently exists at this OID'.
I can use the asyncGetCmd command to get multiple oids but this is not what i want.
I would basically need to open a thread for each oid and scan it individually which is a very inefficient method.
For example:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, error

def cbFun_OID(sendRequestHandle, errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds, cbCtx):
(authData, transportTarget) = cbCtx
for oid, val in varBinds:
    print val.prettyPrint()
ip='192.168.0.101'
cmdGen = cmdgen.AsynCommandGenerator()
cmdGen.asyncGetCmd(
   cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
   cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
   ((1,3,6,1,2,1,43,10,2,1,4,1,1),),
   (cbFun_OID, (cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0), cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)))))
cmdGen.asyncGetCmd(
   cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
   cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
   ((1,3,6,1,2,1,43,5,1,1,1,1,123456),),
   (cbFun_OID, (cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0), cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)))))
cmdGen.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
```

How can I use pysnmp to get multiple oids even if some of the oids don't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to gather existing variables from SNMP v1 response containing non-existing variables? In that case I'm not sure that goes well with SNMP standards. As per RFC 2576:

```
4.1.2.3.1. If the error-status is anything other than noError,
  ...
  -  The variable binding list of the response PDU SHALL be made
     exactly the same as the variable binding list that was received
     in the original request.
```

Since GET request normally contain NULLs as values, you are not going to [reliably] receive any values from SNMP v1 Agent whenever at least one variable is missing.

I'm referring to v1->v2c PDU translation here because pysnmp API you use works as a v2c entity at the PDU API level regardless of SNMP version peer is talking.

If you think your particular v1 Agent still returns something meaningful even along with error-status being reported, you could use [packet-level API](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v1arch/manager/cmdgen/get-v1.html) to work with SNMPv1 PDU, as that would not invoke v1->v2c PDU translation code trashing everything in v1 response. Before trying that you may wish to [enable pysnmp debugging](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/index.html) to see what is actually in the v1 RESPONSE PDU you are getting.

If you think this pysnmp behaviour is against SNMP standards, please elaborate your point.